# Using T-SQL with Oracle DB

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using T-SQL query directly in Microsoft SQL Server Studio's Query window against to a large Oracle DB, and my SQL server is 2005.

I have created a linked server as myOracleServer. By using the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myOracleServer..owner.myTable WHERE id = 1000 AND Dt = '2009-02-26'
```

It take more than 1 minute to make just one call. For a small size table it is OK, but myTable on Oracle side is very large with millions of rows data.

What I found out is that I could use OPENQUERY to make a similar call with SQL query as  a pass-through one. The result is very fast. The execution time is 00:00:02!

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myOracleServer, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM owner.myTable WHERE ...');
```

The problem I have is that the query is not a constant string. I may change id and Dt values in the query, something like:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ownwer.myTable WHERE id = ' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR)...
```

OPENQUERY does not support a variable as query string nor expression.

Is there any other way to get the pass-through query to Oracle with fast performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure out a solution to resolve slowness issue when I try to pass a query from SQL 2005 server to an Oracle db.

There are three ways to do it. The **first one** is something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myOracleServer..owner.myTable 
  WHERE id = 1000 AND Dt = '2009-02-26'
```

If the table on Oracle side is a big one, with 3M rows of data for example, the execution time is very long. Today I tried it again on my SQL server and it took about 2'44" just for one query (maybe the table is very busy during business days).

The **second method** is to use OPENQUERY, as I stated in my question:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENQUERY(myOracleServer, N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
  owner.myTable WHERE id = 1000 AND Dt = TO_DATE(''2009-02-26'')');
```

It is very fast. I run it again and the execution time is 00:00:00, stunning fast! However, the problem with this method is that OPENQUERY does NOT support variable as a query.

Actually, I found this method and was very exited about the result late at work yesterday. I wrote a blog [on this issue](http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-openquery-for-oracle-db.html) last night. This morning when I tried to put this into production (a stored procedure), I could not use OPENQUERY since in my case, a variable query has to be built on id and date.

The good news is that I found the **third way**, an excellent solution to the issue:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM owner.myTable WHERE id = ' + 
  CAST(@id AS VARCHAR) + N' AND Dt = TO_DATE(''' + @dt +
  N''', ''yyyy-mm--dd'')');
EXEC (@sql) AT myOracleServer;
```

The key point here is to use EXEC with AT to specify a remote server or linked server, and don't forget to use () to bracket @sql variable.  The execution time is 00:00:00!

My bog will be updated this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000)
SET @sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM owner.MyTable WHERE id = " + CAST(@id to varchar(9))
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myOracleServer, @Sql)
```

Comment: as I mentioned OPENQUERY does support variable. See msdn for OPENQUERY.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at it. Outside the box, you could create a "temp" sproc with the statement, but it would be a bit of overkill unless the perf difference was absolutely stunning. I wonder if a CLR proc is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a View based on that query?  If that works you should be able to use the View as if it were a local table.

Comment: If it does as local table, that's the reason to cause low, I think. I like pass-through query, but not working if it is not const for OPENQUERY.